# Wamp : Localhost timeout

Tags: timeout, localhost, wamp, wampserver

yesterday wamp was running great. Tomorrow it didnt. I uninstalled it. Then :
I install wamp. I start it, it is orange. I change the Apache port to **8181**, it turns **green**. I launch localhost on **8181**, it loads until **timeout**.

command prompt sais port is not used.

What to do please ?

My wamp server is **"wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10"**

In httpd.conf there is Listen 0.0.0.0:8181 Listen [::0]:8181 and 8181 is dedicated to : httpd.exe

There is **no error** in apache error log and php erro log files.

Comment: User the WAMPServer menus to change port number, then it will make the change in all the right places and not miss any, _which I believe you have_

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest your first port of call would be to check the WAMP logs.

On Windows these can be found in your WAMP directory /logs. I.E.

```
C:\wamp\logs
```

If there is a more fundamental error, it may be logged in the Window events log.

Comment: apache logs are clean `
[Sun Aug 27 14:47:14.795628 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13488:tid 576] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10076
[Sun Aug 27 14:47:15.346178 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 10076:tid 472] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Aug 27 14:47:15.385816 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10076:tid 472] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.`

Comment: Have you checked that your httpd.conf changes are correct - maybe even revert them.

Also probably worth checking that the port has bound by typing "netstat -a  -b" into a command terminal. This will display all connections/ports and their associated/creator executable. Check you can see the port you've specified bound by Apache or httpd.exe

Comment: Thx, yep there is `Listen 0.0.0.0:8181
Listen [::0]:8181` and 8181 is dedicated to : httpd.exe take a look here https://pastebin.com/p4USu7t6

Comment: I disabled Avast and it works, how to say to avast to allow Apache Please ??

Comment: I'd try this:
1) Go to "Settings"
2) Go to "Troubleshooting"
3) Expand "Redirect Settings"
4) Under "WEB" look for ignored address
5) Add localhost
6) Open browser and visit your localhost page.
Also make sure you have the latest version of Avast

Comment: Thanks but I cant see WEB, I have MAIL only